# Screen protection for eReader

Tags: ebook-readers, e-ink

Is it useful or advisable to get screen protection for eReader?
Also does anti-reflective layer makes any good or bad difference with the eInk screen?

Comment: There is a huge difference between eInk devices that have a touchscreen and/or build in light, and those that do not. Which are you interested in? Both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eink devices usually don't have screens with a smooth surface, they have a slight roughness, in order to simulate the look and feel of printed paper and to prevent unwanted light reflections on the surface during reading.

Applying a protective film over it will remove this feature; I don't know if such films with a non-smooth surface are in existance, but even in this case I suppose it won't adhere well to the ereader surface, causing unwanted blurriness.

The best option to protect an eink device, in my opinion, would be to use something like a sleeve or a full cover.

Comment: I am buying the cover, and I also wanted the film. I have Boox M92 and I plan to use it with a lot of pen writing. Also I heard it has a fragile screen, so... But your logic is convincing!

Answer (score 4):

I have 3 eReaders and Sekhemty's answer applies  to the one without touchscreen/self-lighting like my Sony PRS-T1.

The other two have glass fronts (Bookeen Odysey HD and the venerable Sony PRS-700). Those glass fronts are hard enough not to need any protection in the form of semi-permanent stick on film, assuming you are just using your fingers for selection.

Comment: I also have a somewhat recent ereader with touchscreen and incorporated light (a Kobo Glo) and I still prefer to use a cover. It is true that its screen is resistant, but the cover protect it from dust when I don't use it, and accidental scratches when I put it in the pocket of a jacket or inside a briefcase, where other items could scratch or dirty it.

Comment: @Sekhemty Do you mean an adhesive cover, or just a sleeve for transport? The PRS-700 has a cover, and the Bookeen I have not gotten around yet to buy one for.

Comment: I have this one http://www.geckocovers.com/kobo-glo-slimfit-cover.html

Comment: @Sekhemty that looks like the cover I have for the Sony.

Comment: I don't use any protective film on my Cybook Bookeen and it has no scratches. The glass is hard.